# Prototype.js, AJAX form submission occasionally returns status 0, XHR stays in readyState 1

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, prototypejs, form-submit

I've got an odd problem here with Prototype 1.7.0 and an AJAX form submission using form.request().

The response status is either 202 or 200 depending on whether the server expects to be polled again with the same form submission after a timeout. 200 indicates that the response contents are done and are to be displayed to the user (backend uses WebWork's execAndWait-interceptor to execute a long-running job).

The problem is that most of the time, everything works just fine. However, occasionally, the response comes back as status code 0 and XMLHTTPRequest readyState 1. Firebug indicates correct response codes are coming from the backend, and that the actual response contents are fine, it's just that Prototype's on200 and on202 handlers do not fire (on0 does).

It appears there are similar issues reported over the Internet, but there is no conclusive solution. Is this some well known problem?

Answer (score 0):

A response code 0 from prototype means that it can't communicate with the server. You can remedy this by adding an "on0: function() {}" event handler in your request.

How you handle it is up to you...either alert the user that something went wrong, and redisplay their form, or silently try and re-submit your request to the backend in a loop. If you choose the second option, set a wait timeout and each time you can't talk to the server multiply it by some factor so you don't infinite loop their browser.

You might also want to look into queuing these requests on the client-side so you're only firing one at a time, in order.

Hope that helps.